# How to style React Virtuoso scrollbar?

Tags: reactjs

In order to ensure a style consistency across devices, I would like to use "react-simple-scrollbar". It works fine with a classic overflow div, but not with Virtuoso. How to implement it?

Here is the code:

```js
const Scrollbar = styled(SimpleBarReact)`
  .simplebar-scrollbar::before {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Scrollbar>
      <Virtuoso
        style={{ height: "400px" }}
        totalCount={200}
        itemContent={(index) => <div>Item {index}</div>}
      />
    </Scrollbar>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `components` prop:

```
<Virtuoso
   totalCount={totalCount}
   itemContent={(index) => <div>Item {index}</div>}
   components={{
     Scroller: React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
          <Scrollable forwardedRef={ref} />
     )),
   }}
/>
```

`virtuoso` has pretty good [documentation](https://virtuoso.dev/customize-structure/). Also here is the full `components` [API ref](https://virtuoso.dev/api/interfaces/_interfaces_.components)